# Introduce the data transfer object pattern because of one requirement or put code in the business object?

Tags: c#, business-objects, dto

I have 3 entities and they relate to each other in this way:

```
1 Release has N Testplan
1 Template has N Testplan
```

In order to create a Testplan I need to choose from a list of available releases and templates therefore I have created this DTO:

```
public class TestplanDTO
{
        public IEnumerable<Template> Templates { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Release> Releases { get; set; }
}
```

If I would put this code in the Testplan business object seems wrong to me because a testplan does not have multiple templates or releases.

I ask myself now should I really introduce the DTO pattern just for this case or what do you think about putting that code in the Testplan BO?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it rather be

```
public class TestplanDTO
{
    public TemplateDTO Template { get; set; }
    public ReleaseDTO Release { get; set; }
}
```

?

Your DTO class suggests that 1 TestPlan has N Teplates and 1 TestPlan has N Releases which is in contrary to what you have presented at the beginning.

The other part of question (should you really introduce DTO pattern) cannot be answered without broader context.

**Edit**

I think I start to understand. If you need to show lists of available templates and releases then yes, you can have it like

```
public class TestplanDTO
{
    public TemplateDTO Template { get; set; }
    public ReleaseDTO Release { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TemplateDTO> AvailableTemplates { get; }
    public IEnumerable<ReleaseDTO> AvailableReleases { get; }
}
```

Comment: If it would be rather like you suggested then I would not need a TestplanDTO because my Testplan BO has already a Template and Release property. In order to create a Testplan the user has to choose from a list of template names and release names. Both collections could also be of type <string> but lets stick for now to the <Template> and <Release>. Got it? What more context do you need?

Comment: But why has the TestplanDTO collections of type <TemplateDTO> and <ReleaseDTO> and not Release or Template? What purpose and more benefit has that?

Comment: And what's your reason to introduce DTOs at all?

Comment: Ok it seems I was not successfull explaining you why I had to introduce the TestplanDTO. I try again. I could also take my existing Testplan BO and put there 2 collections of type <Release> and <Template>. Now I do not need a DTO BUT the business logic in my Testplan BO is not: 1 Testplan has N Templates or 1 Testplan has N Releases. This is the requirement of the Presentation Layer only. Thus I had to use the TestplanDTO (Sepearation of Concerns here too)

Comment: Ok. Then you have to decide. Either you thoroughly separate concerns and introduce TestplanDTO, TemplateDTO and ReleaseDTO or you separate them just a little and you let TestplanDTO contain Template and Release instead of TemplateDTO and ReleaseDTO. Neither is better, at least it is impossible to decide at this point. I tend to separate concerns entirely so that if I introduce xxxDTO then it contains yyyyDTO rather than yyyy but it is a matter of style and not a strict obligation.